# Do Principal Upanishads mention Sat Chit Ananda as attributes of Brahman?

Tags: upanishads

In Principal Upanishads(Not Minor like Tejobindu) is Brahman mentioned as Sat Chit and Ananda? Please include Sanskrit verse to highlighten them with along with English translation.

Comment: It is already mentioned inhttps://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45833/how-is-nirguna-brahman-nirguna-if-he-is-sachidananda

Comment: Sir I am looking for exact words. Sat and Chit. Above verses quoted mention Existance as Satya and Chit as Vijnana. Is there a compound word in Principal Upanishads @GIRIBLR

Comment: Okay, vijnana is usually translated as consciousness. See Wikipedia. Sat, Anantha, ananda are all directly mentioned in the Upanishads. Maybe chit is also mentioned but it is definitely mentioned by Shankara in his works.

Comment: Prajnanam Brahman (Aitareya Upanishad 3.1.3)
Satyam Jnanam Anantam Brahman (Taittariya Upanishad 2.1.1)
Vijnanam Anandam Brahman (Bruhadaranyaka Upanishad 3.9.28)

Comment: Sat-chit-ananda are not Brahman's qualities. Qualities or attributes in Vedanta are viewed as limitations pertaining to objects, that are subject to change. Brahman is not an object. Sat-chit-ananda are what are called "Swarupa Lakshana" in Advaita. They are Brahman's innate nature.

Comment: In so far as I remember, even Shankara does not use the specific combination sat-chit-ananda for brahman anywhere in his prasthAnatraya bhAshyas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the etymology reason for the swarupa order in the construction of the word "Sat-chit-ananda"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28677/what-is-the-etymology-reason-for-the-swarupa-order-in-the-construction-of-the-wo)

Comment: Adi Shankaracharya explicitly mentions Lord Dakshinamoorthy as “Sachchidanandaroop” in his Dakshinamoorthy Stotram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think you will find the exact words, Sat, Chit, Ananda to describe Brahman in the principal ten upanishads. As you said, it is found in minor upanishads such as Tejobindu upanishad and the words of Adi Shankara.

However, you can find the words, Sat, Prajnana/Vijnana, Ananda, Anantha to describe Brahman in the principal upanishads, as seen below.

> Prajnanam Brahman (Aitareya Upanishad 3.1.3)
>
> Satyam Jnanam Anantam Brahman (Taittariya Upanishad 2.1.1)
>
> Vijnanam Anandam Brahman (Bruhadaranyaka Upanishad 3.9.28)

Vijnana is normally translated as consciousness. So Brahman having the svarupa lakshana of Existence, Consciousness, Bliss and Infinite comes from these sources.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned,but **not in the Upanishads**

Gheranda Samhita has this statement:

> ** I am Brahman [Supreme Soul] alone, and nothing else; my form is truth, consciousness and bliss (satcitananda); I am eternally free**

[This is the link for the Gheranda Samhita,page 57 of the text,4th verse](http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/GherandaSamhitaSanEng.pdf)

It explicitly mentions *Sat,Chit and Ananda*